# How to join 3 tables and get sum from result of individual joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I have the following scenario:
Table: **users** : user_id, username ,...
Table: **login**: user_id, login_date, ...
Table: **point**: user_id, points, point_time
Joins will be on the basis of users.user_id with other tables.

Now, I want to get count of all the logins as well as sum of all the points earned by the user.
Now, when I do:

```
select users.user_id,count(*) from users
inner join login on users.user_id=login.user_id
group by users.user_id
```

It returns count as 36(for example).
Whenever I run:

```
select users.user_id,count(*),sum(points) from users
inner join point on users.user_id=point.user_id
group by users.user_id
```

It returns sum as 400(for example) and count as 2.

But if I combine both the queries:

```
select users.user_id,count(*),sum(points) from users
inner join login on users.user_id=login.user_id
inner join point on users.user_id=point.user_id
group by users.user_id
```

It returns count as 72 (36 * 2) and sum as 800 (400 *2).
Twice because of multiple userIds present.
I tried several things like combining with distincts but nothing seems to work. Please help.
Better if it's possible with joins alone. Thanks in advance. I am using mysql with Php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sum the points in a subquery and select distinct logins in the count

```
select users.user_id,l.login,p.points from users
inner join (select user_id, count(1) login from login
       group by login) as l on users.user_id=login.user_id
inner join (select user_id, sum(point) as point 
        from point group by user_id ) as p on users.user_id=point.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do your count by joining in your login table and then including a subquery to get your count of points:

```
select users.user_id, count(*) as login_count,
  (select sum(points) from point 
   where point.user_id = users.user_id) as points_sum 
from users
inner join login on users.user_id=login.user_id
group by users.user_id
```